# Solr equivalent of SQL BETWEEN for numeric fields

Tags: performance, solr

Hoping for some pointers to speed up some (very) slow solr queries in version 3.4.0.

I have an index of about 6-million documents.  Each document is quite small, and contains two `solr.TrieDoubleField`s; "start" and "end".

```
<fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
----
<field name="start" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="end" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

When querying I need to perform the SQL equivalent of:

```
WHERE @input BETWEEN Start AND End
```

To do this I'm writing my query as:

```
start:[* TO @input] AND end:[@input TO *]
```

The query succeeds, returning the correct document, but with a QTime of ~4,500; most other queries are well below 100.

What can be modified to improve performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you should try the [Function Range (frange)](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionRangeQParserPlugin.html) query parser in Solr. Please see the introductory blog post - [Ranges Over Functions in Solr 1.4](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/06/ranges-over-functions-in-solr-14/) for more details on how to use the Function Range query parser. 
(**Note** this should apply to all versions of Solr greater that 1.4 as well)

So I think something like the following should work...

```
`?q=*:*&fq={!frange l=0 u=<@input>}start
    &fq{!frange l=<@input> u=<number larger than greatest value>}end`
```

I am not sure if you can use wildcards for the upper and lower bounds, probably not...

Comment: Thanks!  I'd tried the frange's last night (along with filterquery's) without much luck, but your query is running plenty fast (about 200ms, versus 4500 for all other accurate queries0